# Reinstalling software

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I have just accidentally uninstalled a piece of software applicable to my new printer, using the uninstall command in the Control Panel. I was looking for something else! How do I undelete or reinstall it if I don't know the name of the software? I checked and there is no undo command under Edit.

Comment: [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/restore-system-files-and-settings) to a restore point with a date/time earlier than when you uninstalled the printer software.

Comment: call up your printer manufacturer and they'll talk you through what to do - where and what to download

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the manufacturer's website you should be able to find out the model of the printer and there should be a download option for the drivers. If you can't find out the exact model (usually they should have pictures and instructions for how to find it) there will usually be an e-mail address and/or phone number or similar for you to contact them and they will be able to give you instructions on how to find out.

Failing that if you are using a Windows system you should be able to use something called a 'Restore Point' to roll your system back to the point at which you had the driver. If you tell me what OS and what version you are running on I should be able to find you some info...

Comment: Is it possible to view flags suggested by others before they are accepted? I wasn't aware of the feature but if it's available it would be very useful to know about.

Comment: I can usually see accepted flags... they show as a red-shaded box (below the comments). However, I don't see one here. Perhaps I need to clean my cache... Certainly I am seeing a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out) sc.iasds01.com/dtc?asid=8cb622fc-ff19-11e5-9a69-002590882ece" error in the console for this site. Might that be why I'm not seeing the flag... or has it not been accepted, and maybe people with more rep can see flags that aren't accepted?